# Finding angle of rotation of an ellipse

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

Suppose I have the ellipse
$$
x^2 -2xy +4y^2 = 1
$$

How can I find the angle at which this ellipse is rotated?

I have tried to assign $x=\cos\theta, y=0.5\sin\theta$ but I don't know if that's the way

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far :)

Comment: Have you considered rewriting as a sum of quadratics?  For example, $$x^2-2xy+4y^2=(2y-ax)^2+(1-a^2)x^2=4y^2-4axy+a^2x^2 +(1-a^2)x^2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** look for the eigenvectors of
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
-1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: Just to point out why this matrix is interesting: the ellipse equation can be rewritten to $$\left(\matrix{x & y }\right)\left(\matrix{1&-1\\-1&4}\right)\left(\matrix{x \\ y}\right) = 1$$